# Does /l̥/ in reconstructed Latin represent a voiceless (alveolar) lateral approximate or something else?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, phoneme

> Latin *facultās* presumably developed from an original **faklitāts* (via **fakl̥tāts* > **fakiltāts* > *facultās*) . . .
>
> <sup>—[*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/faculty)</sup>

Does the /l̥/ in **fakl̥tāts* represent a voiceless (alveolar) lateral approximate, or does it represent something else? Does /l̥/ represent different allophones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a symbol borrowed from Proto-Indo-European—linguists working with PIE regularly use **l̥* for something like IPA `/l̩/`, a syllabic lateral, not a voiceless one.

However, I'm not quite sure why the authors of that article posit a syllabic lateral here. I've never seen syllabic resonants proposed for any stage of Latin before.

Comment: The reconstructions in the quoted MW dictionary entry are taken from Michael Weiss *Outline of the Historical and Comparative Grammar of Latin*, one of the best historical grammars of Latin.